# Is the integral of continuous functions over a second argument continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, continuity

Let $(X,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a measure space and $Y,Z$ be a normed spaces. Suppose a function $$f: X \times Y \to Z$$ is measurable in its first argument and continuous in its second argument. Moreover, suppose there exists an Lebesgue-integrable function $g: X \to \mathbb R$ so that, for all $y \in Y$, $||f(x,y)|| \leq g(x)$.

Does this imply that the Lebesgue integral
$$
\int_X d\mu \ f(\cdot,y)
$$
is continuous in $y$? If not, what additional conditions are required? Thanks!

Comment: This is obvious from DCT and the fact that $\|\int [f(x,y_n)-f(x,y)]d\mu(x)\| \leq \int \|f(x,y_n)-f(x,y)\|d\mu (x)$.

Comment: Indeed it is obvious! Thanks for helping me see that. Much appreciated.